# How to get item source from inoreader feed?

Tags: rss, simplepie

I have a inoreader tag feed url with below format:

```xml
<item>
    <title></title>
    <link></link>
    <description></description>
    <pubDate></pubDate>
    <category></category>
    <dc:creator></dc:creator>
    <source url=" "> XYZ </source>
    <guid isPermaLink="false"> </guid>
</item>*
```

Example of the feed is : http://www.inoreader.com/stream/user/1005908176/tag/devotional
I could not fetch itewm source i.e., XYZ using simplepie or magpie.
Also I could not get `<dc:creator>`

How to fetch those parameters using any rss parser?
Also can I get these parameters to MySQL?

Comment: What do you mean by "I could not fetch"? Once the feed has been fetched, are you able to parse it and get the value for `title` for example?

Comment: Sorry for my English. While parsing, I could not "item Source" means in example it is XYZ

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286333/getting-data-from-inoreader-feed-using-php